# FileAlreadyExists pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, error-handling, pyspark

I cannot find a way to remove a hdfs output file in hadoop pyspark.
Using the commands:

```
hadoop fs -rmdir "path/outputFile.csv"
```

When I run a new job with same output filename, I get the error FileAlreadyExist.

Anyone know how to handle this situation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using dataframes and your output in dataframe format, you overwrite it like below.

```
df.write('filepath/filename.csv', mode='overwrite')
```

Answer (score 4):

From command line, you can use the command:

```
hdfs dfs rm -r /path/to/myDir/
```

From Spark, you can do (in Scala):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem,Path}
import java.net.URI

val dirPath = "/path/to/my/dir/"
val fileSystem = FileSystem.get(URI.create(dirPath), sqlContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
fileSystem.delete(new Path(dirPath), true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using pyspark :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["hadoop", "fs", "-rm", "path/outputFile.csv"])
```

You may use call to perform any task that we do in command line

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do the following:

```
import os
os.system("hadoop fs -rmdir "path/outputFile.csv"")
```